# Java: Access class within a method

Tags: java, class

I would like have one method declare two Strings and assign them values. Then have another method to read those values.

I have this structure:

```
public class ABC extends CDE implements EFG {
    public void firstMethod(valueOne, valueTwo) {
        class TestClass {
            public String testValue = valueOne;
            public String anotherValue = valueTwo;
        }
    }

    public void readMethod() {
        // HERE I WANT TO READ testValue AND ASSIGN IT A NEW VALUE
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

And is there a better way?

Comment: Why not declare `testValue` and `anotherValue` as properties of the `ABC` class instead of declaring a local class?

Comment: How is this supposed to make any sense?

Comment: Your code does not compile; `valueOne` and `valueTwo` are missing their types. --- Why do you declare a class within a method? --- To pass information from one method to another, you should use parameters.

Comment: What you are doing is declaring a class and never creating any instance of it. So the values are never set and cannot be read anyway. What is the inner class supposed to represent?

Comment: @ernest_k Somewhere else I will call firstMethod to declare the two strings, and later call readMethod to read the two Strings and change their values.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you are using an inner class instead of plain old fields.

Comment: @Alichino your TestClass (even if this code compiled) would not exist out of the firstMethod method. you can't "read" that from readMethod

Comment: especially if you are a 'noob', you should start at the beginning.

Comment: @ernest_k I did what you suggested in the end. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you need a class?

May be a simple field declaration will be enough:

```
   public class ABC extends CDE implements EFG {
        public String testValue;
        public String anotherValue;


        public void firstMethod(String valueOne, String valueTwo) {
             // do whatever you wish with testValue and anotherValue
        }

        public void readMethod() {        
            // here you have access to both variables        
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will fit your criteria?
What you are currently asking for is impossible due to the scope of the inner class.

You could also initialize this private class instance in your constructor.

```
public class Sample {
    class TestClass {
        public String testValue;
        public String anotherValue;
    }

    private TestClass localTest = new TestClass();

    public void firstMethod(valueOne, valueTwo) {
        localTest.testValue = valueOne;
        localTest.anotherValue = valueTwo;
    }

    public void readMethod() {
        localTest.testValue = "test1";
        localTest.anotherValue = "anotherValue";

        System.out.println(localTest.testValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Initialization?

Comment: Have you tried it? You are going to get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the local class global and set/read values via instance:

```
public class ABC extends CDE implements EFG {

    class TestClass {
        public String testValue = valueOne;
        public String anotherValue = valueTwo;
    }
    private testClassInstance = new TestClass()

    public void firstMethod(valueOne, valueTwo) {
         testClassInstance.testValue = valueOne
         testClassInstance.anotherValue = valueTwo
    }

    public void readMethod() {
        System.out.println(testClassInstance.valueOne)
        System.out.println(testClassInstance.valueTwo)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you want to do is to create a [POJO](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pojo-vs-java-beans/) that holds `testValue` and `anotherValue` and declare the class outside of your component class, e.g.:

```
class ExampleBean {
  private String testValue;
  private String anotherValue;

  //getters and setters
}
```

Once done, you can hold the reference of that class into your component class and access the value, e.g.:

```
public class ABC extends CDE implements EFG {
    ExampleBean exampleBean = new ExampleBEan();
    public void firstMethod(valueOne, valueTwo) {
        exampleBean.setValueOne(valueOne);
        exampleBean.setAnotherValue(valueTwo);
    }

    public void readMethod() {
        String value = exampleBean.getValueOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? Why not just use fields?

Comment: Updated the answer, realised it immediately after posting.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a class withing a method , which is not right

You need to understand what a class and a method really mean ( Google Java OOP ) :

1- You should create a class and declare the variables you want

2- make constructors for the default values

3- make setters to set (assign) these values

4- make getters to read those values